# ¿Es posible pasar variables en php sin usar la url o un form?

Tags: php

Conocen alguna manera de pasar variables sin utilizar form o la url?
En si, estaría necesitando una forma de pasar variables sin utilizar lo anteriormente mencionado debido a que si cambio los datos de la url podría "vulnerar la seguridad de la pagina" modificando la url haciendo que obtenga estos datos y no estaría haciendo un formulario donde el accionar de este tenga que ver con un botón.
Tambien se me ocurrio utilizar session, pero no entiendo el manejo de este debido a que segui tutoriales y no logro obtener resultado.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: el pasar variables por get o por post es como trabaja toda la web y vulnerar la seguridad de la pagina solo se logra cuando esta mal programada, mi consejo sigue mas tutoriales.

Comment: Puedes usar Ajax o Fetch como alternativa, de todos modos la seguridad estará garantizada cuando establezcas en cada caso los filtros adecuados y uses las herramientas adecuadas según el uso que vayas a dar a esos datos.

Comment: Puedes dar detalles del problema??

Comment: Buenas! Ahi lo solucione! Siempre estuve usando mal la sesión.
Nunca me percate de que en cada pagina tiene que estar el session_start().

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que tu información viaje del front al backend de forma seguro adicional a POST y SSL debes cifrar los datos con RSA.